# Query on XSL for mapping different versions of the same schema

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I understand XSL at a conceptual level and haven't done a great deals of XSL sheets myself.

The problem that we are trying to solve is this:

The application works with partners who all work with different versions of our schema. Eg. V2 and V3.

THe application has a data model which is a superset of all the schemas (in this case V2 and V3).

The transformation from V2 and V3 to the application data model should easily be achieved using XSL.

Now when V4 and V5 comes through, we need to build XSLs for V4 and V5 and i am wondering if there are easy ways to build on what is created for V2 and V3 and simply add only the additional elements/changes that are relevant to V4 and V5.

At a high level i don't see a problem in doing this but i don't have adequate hands on knowledge in XSL to see how it can be done.

I beleive this is a pretty common problem and some standard patterns/approaches are used by the XSL practitioners.

Appreciate pointers and XSL samples.

Thanks

Manglu

Answer (score 3):

Stylesheet re-use is accomplished in XSLT using the [xsl:import](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#element-import) and [xsl:include](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#element-include) elements, which are described in detail at the provided links.

In short, your new stylesheets need only handle new elements and import/include stylesheets that define templates for existing structures.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to write a set of stylesheets that convert V2->V3, V3->V4, V4->V5, and so on; then do the conversion from Vm to Vn by assembling the right pipeline of transformers. This puts bounds on the complexity, and enables you to drop the older converters when the older schema versions eventually fall into disuse.